# ST_Line_Substring doesn't work

Tags: postgis, function

I want to split some line strings using `ST_Line_Substring`.

My basic query works:

```
SELECT
  ST_LineLocatePoint(b.geom_way,ST_ClosestPoint(a.geom,b.geom_way)) as Loc_Point
 FROM splitpoints a
 
CROSS JOIN LATERAL 
  (SELECT
      id, geom_way
      FROM osm_2po_4pgr
      ORDER BY a.geom <-> osm_2po_4pgr.geom_way
     LIMIT 1
   ) AS b
```

If I try do add `ST_Line_Substring(b.geom_way,0,1)` in line 3, it doesn't work anymore:

```
ERROR:  function st_line_substring(geometry, integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 6:   ST_Line_Substring(b.geom_way,0,1) as test2
          ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 143
```

I already tried to CAST the arguments (0 and 1) to float explicitly `(ST_Line_Substring(b.geom_way,0::float,1::float))`. `b.geom_way` is a simple linestring:

```
SELECT ST_astext(b.geom_way)....

LINESTRING(10.0349278 52.08885,10.0350045 52.0883998,10.0349549 52.0875119)
```

Everything looks like it should be according to the docs (https://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ST_Line_Substring.html):

> geometry ST_Line_Substring(geometry a_linestring, float startfraction,
> float endfraction);

What's wrong?

Comment: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineSubstring.html

Comment: Current PostGIS version is 3.1 https://postgis.net/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function is called `ST_LineSubstring`, not `ST_Line_Substring`, in modern PostGIS. ;)

Comment: Thx. That's it. Although a bit confusing...